# How to transform any string into a print statement which produces that string when execued in python

Tags: python

So, basically what I'm trying to do is read some text in from disk and create a series of print statements that when executed will reproduce the text that was read in.

For instance in my file contains one line like:

> I said, "It's a nice day."

Then my program should produce the following python code as output:

```
print "I said, \"It\'s a nice day.\n\""
```

Note that I don't mean it should execute the above code. It should merely generate the above string.

I came up with the following code, which works for some cases:

```
import sys
import re

filename = sys.argv[1]

infile = open(filename)

for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.encode('string-escape')
    sys.stdout.write("print \""+line+"\"\n")
```

This seems to work for some lines but not others.  When I run this code on itself, it doesn't work for the double quotes. They are not properly escaped for instance.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Use `repr` to get the proper quoting:

```
with open(filename) as r:
    for line in r:
        line = line.strip()
        sys.stdout.write('print %s\n' % repr(line))
```

Comment: Why are you using backquotes around the string?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.encode('string-escape')` (since that only seems to escape the `\`'s, why not the following:

```
line.replace('"', r'\"')
```

This will then escape those `"`s for you.

You also might wish to do the same thing for `'`'s since they also create strings.